# Objective-C Subclassing: Two subclass instances seem to point to the same instance

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, subclass

I'm a little (actually, a lot) confused as to why I receive the output listed at the bottom when I execute the code below. The Insect and Mammal instances should be two separate objects with separate instance variables. Both calls to [super initAttributes] should initialize each instance independently, each having passed **self**. So why do both the *insect* and *mammal* instances have the same values when displayed? It seems as if both instances are pointing to the same object in memory.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

**Animal** Class

```
//Interface

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Animal : NSObject

-(id) initAttributes: (NSString *) initName Legs: (int) initLegs Arms: (int) initArms;
-(void) display;

@end

//Implementation

#import "Animal.h"

@implementation Animal

NSString *name;
int legs, arms;

-(id) initAttributes: (NSString *) initName Legs: (int) initLegs Arms: (int) initArms
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        name = initName;
        legs = initLegs;
        arms = initArms;
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) display
{
    NSLog(@"Name: %@ Legs: %i Arms: %i", name, legs, arms);
}

@end
```

**Insect Class**

```
//Interface

#import "Animal.h"

@interface Insect : Animal

-(id) initInsect: (NSString *) initName;

@end

//Implementation

#import "Insect.h"

@implementation Insect

-(id) initInsect: (NSString *) initName
{
    self = [super initAttributes: initName Legs: 8 Arms: 0];

    if (self)
    {
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

**Mammal Class**

```
//Interface

#import "Animal.h"

@interface Mammal : Animal

-(id) initMammal: (NSString *) initName;

@end

//Implementation


#import "Mammal.h"

@implementation Mammal

-(id) initMammal: (NSString *) initName
{
    self = [super initAttributes: initName Legs: 2 Arms: 2];

    if (self)
    {
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

**Main**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Insect.h"
#import "Mammal.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Insect *insect = [[Insect alloc] initInsect: @"Spydor"];
        Mammal *mammal = [[Mammal alloc] initMammal: @"Platypus"];

        [insect display];
        [mammal display];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

Name: Platypus Legs: 2 Arms: 2
Name: Platypus Legs: 2 Arms: 2

Comment: It's my class, and they have 8 legs. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume this is homework, so here is a hint: 
The error is with your variable declaration. Don't use global variables for polymorphism.

Comment: For someone learning the language this can be a pretty subtle problem.

Comment: @user1433587 [Start here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-SW1). Specifically, read the _Class implementation_ section and do not miss the note in the _Class Interface_ section.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I'm on the cusp of understanding. Not homework; just trying to learn Objective-C. I will take a look at the Apple Developer site for some more insight.